# Lock editing in some cells but no further protection

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to protect my Excel sheet in a way that prevents editing in certain cells but has all the other protection options disabled. Put differently, the sheet should have the behavior as an unprotected sheet only with cell editing in some cell disabled.

```
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(OldRowCount, 7)).Locked = False
ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=True
```

I'd probably need to set a couple of other properties for the `.Protect`, or maybe I should choose a different method altogether...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are lots of options in the "Protect sheet" dialog - have you looked at those?  If you want to prevent editing, then protecting the sheet is probably the most reliable way to go (subject to all the usual provisos about the strength of the protection, etc, etc).

Comment: @TimWilliams OP wants to `disable all the other protection options`. Is that possible?

Comment: I would say that options are by their nature optional ;-). Unless there's something more specific the OP wants to add its hard to guess exactly what they're looking for. That is, if all the "Allow X" options are checked what can the end-user still not do which they should be able to do?

Comment: Did my solution help you? If so, an accept would be nice.

Comment: Jook, thank you very much for your answer and sorry for my very delayed response: I've had lot of other things in between. I'll test your solution ASAP (1-2 days).

Answer (score 1):

I think the question was just, how to setup this behavior in VBA properly.

A quick use of <kbd>F1</kbd> provides nearly everything necessary. What was wrong, was the use of `Locked`, because it has to be `true` for some cells and false for all others in order to behave like intendet.

Here's my solution:

```
Public Sub Demo()
  With ActiveSheet
    'Deactivate lock for all cells, so they don't be blocked by protection
    .Cells.Locked = False
    'Activate lock for some cells
    'Range(Cells(4, 3), Cells(OldRowCount, 7)).Locked = True
    .Cells(6, 4).Locked = True
    If .ProtectContents Then
      .Unprotect
    Else
      'only contents:=true is really important
      .Protect _
        Password:="", _
        Contents:=True, _
        DrawingObjects:=False, _
        Scenarios:=False, _
        UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
        AllowDeletingColumns:=True, _
        AllowDeletingRows:=True, _
        AllowFiltering:=True, _
        AllowFormattingCells:=True, _
        AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=True, _
        AllowInsertingColumns:=True, _
        AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True, _
        AllowInsertingRows:=True, _
        AllowSorting:=True, _
        AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```